# PHP, 100 divs i need to remove the margin from all the divs in the right corner(without change my wrapper)

Tags: php, html, css

Hello everyone i am a student that this year got into programmng in the university and i am trying to do something in php.

Want i wan to do here is simply remove the margin from all the right divs. I thought since i have 3 of them i can do tha with just if($i%3==0) but that didnt help me.
I will share the code with you and i would really me gratefull to any answers.
Thank a ton in advantage! 
--The code----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper  { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:black; padding:20px;}
.box{width:300px; height:30px; background-color: #ff0000; color:#fff; font-size: 20px; float: left; padding: 10px;text-align:center; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
 .clear {clear:both;}
.box1{margin-right:0px;}
</style>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <?php
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
echo '<div class="box">'.$i.'</div>';

 if($i%3==0){
  echo '<div class="box box1">'.$i.'</div>';
}else {
  echo '<div class="box">'.$i.'</div>';
  }

     ?>
 <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
   </body>


   </html>
```

Comment: You are echoing each div twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`nth-child` pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) in CSS so you don't have to do all the work in PHP.  For example:

```
.box {
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* ... */
}

.box:nth-child(3n+3) {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: i thought of it and thanks for you reply but that doesnt work. It gives me that http://prntscr.com/91px04

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for you helping me.  I finally solved my problem and you guys helped me a lot with your ideas. Here is what i finally have done

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
<style>
 .wrapper  { width: 920px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:black; padding:20px;}
 .box{width:300px; height:30px; background-color: #ff0000; color:#fff; font-size: 20px; float: left;text-align:center; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
 .clear {clear:both;}
 .box1{float:right;margin-right: 0px;}
</style>
   </head>

  <body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <?php
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)


if($i % 3 == 0){
  echo '<div class="box box1">'.$i.'</div>';
}else{
  echo '<div class="box">'.$i.'</div>';

}

  ?>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
  </body>


  </html>
```